# Replicate MATLAB's `eig` in Julia

Tags: matlab, julia, linear-algebra, eigenvector, matrix-factorization

It is known that the Eigen decomposition of a matrix isn't unique.

Yet I wonder if one could replicate MATLAB's `eig` function in Julia.
Namely have exact output up to numeric errors assuming ascending order of the eigen values.

Assuming we set the options of MATLAB's `eig` to their default (`balanceOption`, `balance`, Using `cholesky` for symmetric matrices and `qz` for others as algorithms).

Since MATLAB is using `Intel MKL` so assuming also `MKL.jl` is available in Julia (does it have an effect on Julia for the `eigen` function?).

Comment: Have you tried ? Did you got the same output ?

Comment: @Antonello, Yes, in my code the vectors are very different. Also see https://discourse.julialang.org/t/eigenvalue-calculation-differs-between-julia-and-matlab/31185.

Comment: Since the options for output are different between MATLAB eig, MATLAB eigs, and Julia eigen, it might be easier for you to get an answer if you specify what input and output you need.

Comment: @Bill, Assume we sort both results by the eigenvalues, either ascending or descending, could we do something to ensure the eigenvectors are the same?

Comment: Try sorting and normalizing the answer vectors, and then maybe standardize the order of any negative signs in the vector? Are these complex numbers you are getting for the eigenvalues?

Comment: @Bill, I don't think the only difference is the signs or normalization of the vectors.

Comment: Yes, the order of values in an an eigenvector also matters, and how you define an ordering on complex values may also matter. Whatever you do, you will need to make arbitrary choices of what conversions to make.

Comment: @Bill, the whole question is about being able to generate the same results given that the factorization isn't unique. I'm looking of r a recipe which will create the same set of vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recipe for deciding on a standardized eigenvector.  There are arbitrary choices here to normalize the vector and to sort complex numbers as tuples of (real, complex) and to choose the signs of the eigenvector components so as to have the largest real value in the normalized vector (see comments):

```
using LinearAlgebra

""" compare two complex values as if tuples with (real portion, imaginary portion) """
complexlt(x, y) = (real(x), imag(x)) < (real(y), imag(y))

""" get a kind of canonical normalized form of an eigenvector of matrix A """
function sorted_normalized_eigen(A)
    # julia's eigen returns a struct, with eigenvector as values component of the struct
    m = eigen(A).values
    # sort the normalized form of the eigenvector from least to greatest
    normed1 = sort(normalize(m), lt = complexlt)
    # sort the additive inverse of normalized form of the eigenvector from least to greatest
    normed2 = sort(-1 .* normed1, lt = complexlt)
    # choose the normalized vector with the largest real component as our unique return value
    return complexlt(last(normed1), last(normed2)) ? normed2 : normed1
end

B =  [1 2 3; 3 1 2; 2 3 1]

@show sorted_normalized_eigen(B)

sorted_normalized_eigen(B) = ComplexF64[-0.2314550249431379 - 0.13363062095621225im, -0.2314550249431379 + 0.13363062095621225im, 0.9258200997725515 + 0.0im]
```

Comment: For future readers: The Discourse discussion is linked below the question, but it's worth [highlighting it and its conclusion](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/eigenvalue-calculation-differs-between-julia-and-matlab/31185/18): by default, MATLAB's `eig` doesn't guarantee a fixed order even on its own, and different languages/libraries return different (equivalent) results. The only way to actually have consistency is to sort and normalize yourself like in this answer, and do that uniformly across languages in your code.